# Временные таблицы и статистика

Tags: sql, sql-server

Слышал, что SQL SERVER может использовать устаревшую статистику при использовании временных таблиц, даже если таблица дропается в самом начале вызова процедуры.

1. Правда ли это?
2. Может ли от этого страдать производительность?
3. Как с этим бороться? Достаточно ли указать `WITH RECOMPILE` в начале процедуры или нужно напротив каждого запроса, где используется временная таблица использовать `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`?

Comment: _"Правда ли это?"_ Эмм... ну как вам сказать, наверное может и такое случиться, но и пример обратного я привести могу.